# glossaries alternative text

Tags: glossaries, alias

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{solve}{name={solve},description={to find an answer}}

\makeglossary
\begin{document}

You can \gls{solve} an equation if a 
solution          % HERE 
exists

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I need to link "solution" to `\gls{solve}` despite different spelling.

I assumed `\gls[<alternate text>]{<label>}` exist but it does not.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I can't understand your intention.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I think that "solution" should link to the "solve" glossary entry.

Comment: @aiao: It seems you are looking for `\glslink{foo}{solution}`

Comment: I know this is not popular to do follow ups in the same question but how do I expand this?
How can I define a new command (like `\gls` but for instance `\glscustom`) but it displays a custom combination of the attributes in the `glossaryentry` - without breaking the functionality of the original commands? e.g. Output looks like: `<Name> <user1> <description>`.

Comment: @Sensei I think what you mean is a custom glossary _style_. [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98241/usepackageglossaries-with-3-columns), I think should help.

Comment: @aiao Hmmm correct me if I'm wrong, but this only affects the behavior of the `\printglossary` command. What I would like to do is create text other than only the name or the description of an entry in the reference command like `\gls` without messing with said command's functionality. I wasn't clear about this, sorry.

Comment: @Sensei I got use wrong first time, sorry about that. For the said functionality you could define a new command after package inclusion `\newcommand{\glssensei}{1}{\gls{#1} \glsuseri{#1}}`
[source](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (59 to 65). Usage `\glssensei{<key>}`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back at me. I don't know if this is my document or the command itself but it doesn't work for me. I get 4 diffrent error messages (I tried your command and a modified version of mine  `\newcommand{\glss1}{1}{\glsname{#1} \glsdesc{#1} \glsuseri{#1}}`): `! Illegal parameter number in definition of  .` `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.` `! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry ##1 has not been defined.`. And also I get a Missing `\begin{document}`. I thought new commands are defined between packages and said beginning.

Comment: Just to report back, I made a beginners mistake. Dont use numbers in your commands e.g. `\glss1` instead you would use `\glssone`. -.-' and voilà it's working like a charm. The only problem I'm having now is: My name key is a math expression `$\Delta E_{GP,i}$`. The command `\glsname` can not typeset math even if there is an `\ensuremath` somewhere. Any ideas? P.S.: number of arguments needs to be put into `[ ]` brackets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could either use `\glslink{solve}{solution}` as pointed out by Marco Daniel or, if there are several instances of "solution" in your document, define a `\glsnoun` macro which points to `\glsuseri` and add `user1={solution}` to the glossary entry's definition -- see section 4.1 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossary

\let\glsnoun\glsuseri

\newglossaryentry{solve}{name={solve},description={to find an answer},user1={solution}}

\begin{document}

You can \gls{solve} an equation if a \glsnoun{solve} exists.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `glslink` is the correct answer. Your solution doesn't allow an alternative text.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel My solution seems the proper approch for "fixed" alternative variants which occur several times. Also note that up to six user-defined variants can be provided.

Comment: More than 6 now... I think...