# Display long form (first-use like) entries of non-acronym-type entries

Tags: glossaries

I was searching for 2 hours straight now and I must say the package documentation is extensive but not very clear - frustrating. I'm looking for a way to manually display the first use form (long form) of non-acronym-type entries without resetting the counter. Can somebody help me?

I've learned so far there are indeed commands for acronyms which do exactly that. But used on an entry in a different glossary (main or custom) produces no text.

Edit: First, I like to thank [mafp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21591/mafp) for his answer so far. I should maybe elaborate on my problem some more. I am currently writing on my Bachelor thesis. Since I introduced a good amount of formulas what i would like is to have a glossary for the symbols with a brief description of what they stand for. Additionally, I am thinking about inserting the same definition underneath each formula. One of my entries looks like the following:

```
\newglossaryentry{degvi}{type=symbols,
name=$\Delta E_{GP,i}$,
symbol={MJ},
sort=energie differenz grau verbrauch,
description={Differenz graue Energie und Verbrauch zu Produktion des betrachteten Systems}}
```

which produces an output like this:

[image: Visualizing the code]

Honestly, I would like to see the same output below the equation without typing everything twice. Maybe this isn't the best approach, but I like the idea of having the database of symbols with the automatic glossary creation for reference (e.g., if I'm trying to find an equation with a specific symbol).

Comment: i have trouble understanding the title.  is "none" (= "not any") supposed to be "known" (= something for which the meaning is understood)?  i hesitate to edit this in case it means something else.

Comment: Hi Barbara, english is not my mother tongue. So I suppose you could be right. Feel free to change it. For clarification I try to explain the none in the title: `none` as in `not an acronym`. Because acronym entries have a dedicated command to display `<description><abbrev>` and the other glossaries do not. At least thats what i think.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  indeed, you meant something entirely different from what i was guessing.  i think "non-acronym" is clearer in this situation, and i will edit that in.

Comment: You could also use `\glsentrylong` directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The appropriate command is `\glsfirst{...}`. Use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{%
name={foo},%
description={bar},%
first={first},%
}

\begin{document}
\gls{A}, \gls{A}, \glsfirst{A}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Regarding your updated question, I am concerned with your usage of the `symbol` field, for what you give as a symbol seems to be a unit. Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98287/21591) can point into a better direction.

That being said, if you want to use the glossary entries the way you defined them, you can mimic the output of the glossary like I did here with a `description` environment under the equation. The crucial point is that the format of the output of `\gls{...}` can be set by redefining `\glsdisplayfirst` and `\glsdisplay`. Here, I redefine `\glsdisplayfirst` to show the name, the symbol in parentheses, and the description. If `\gls{degvi}` is used for the first time under equation, the output will be like in the glossary. I also set up a glossary style that mimics your output example, you can ignore that and keep what you currently have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sls}{slo}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{degvi}{%
type=symbols,
name=$\Delta E_{GP,i}$,
symbol={MJ},
sort=energie differenz grau verbrauch,
description={Differenz graue Energie und Verbrauch zu Produktion des betrachteten Systems}%
}

\newglossaryentry{eg}{%
type=symbols,
name=$E_{GP}$,
symbol={MJ},
sort=energie grau verbrauch,
description={Graue Energie des Gebäudes}%
}

%% what should \gls{...} show on first usage
\renewcommand{\glsdisplayfirst}[4]{#1 (#3) #2}

\newglossarystyle{senseistyle}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{description}}%
    {\end{description}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
      \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]
      \space (##4)% the symbol in parentheses
      \space ##3% description
  }%
  % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  % Nothing between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

%% makeindex -s sensei.ist -o sensei.sls -t sensei.slg sensei.slo
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \Delta E_{GP,i} = E_{GP} - ...
\end{equation}
\begin{description}
  \item \gls{degvi}
  \item \gls{eg}
\end{description}

\printglossary[type=symbols,style=senseistyle]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your solution compiles fine and behaves indeed as it is expected. I have two issues with it. 1) Typing all the first= entries seems like alot of work to me for an already existing glossary. 2) I was sure the first-use behaviour was supposed to look like the result in the glossary. But since this is not the case (correct me if I'm wrong) the above code isnt the solution to my problem. Since im running out of character here I'll edit the main question.

Comment: @Sensei I guess you want the `description` entry to show at first use? But then you should use an acronym list explicitly. Or is there any other reason you don't want to use an acronym list here?

Comment: Hmm, actually haven't thought about it. But the reasons from the top of my head would be: A) I already have an acronym list (how would i do a second acronym list?) B) I want to use maybe a third field for the physical unit. Thats about it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I quickly looked into the link to to other question and you are right i should use the user field to specify the units. I just was afraid of creating my own glossary style - it seemed a little complicate to me - so i "abused" the symbol field. Thanks again for your time.