# Custom glossary style: Make glossary as wide as \textwidth

Tags: tables, glossaries, tabularx

WARNING: This is a follow-up question to [Display long form (first-use like) entries of non-acronym-type entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106552/display-long-form-first-use-like-entries-of-none-acronyme-type-entries).

As *mafp* suggested in the other post I went ahead and defined my own glossary-styles (along with some column specifiers) to tackle the unit issue (using the `user1` field). Now my defintion looks like this (style `tabx3col` used in first glossary and `tabx4col` used in second):

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newglossarystyle{tabx3col}{%
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.6\textwidth}R{0.2\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
 % Set the table's header:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
 % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\textbf{##2}}% Name
    & ##3% Description
    & ##5% Page list
    \\% end of row
  }%
 % Sub entries treated the same as level 0 entries:
 %\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
  %\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##5}{##6}}%
 %% Nothing between groups:
 %\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}


\newglossarystyle{tabx4col}{%
 % put the glossary in a longtable environment:
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{L{0.1\textwidth}L{0.1\textwidth}p{0.55\textwidth}R{0.2\textwidth}}}%
  {\end{longtable}}%
 % Set the table's header:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
 % No heading between groups:
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 % Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
   \glstarget{\textbf{##1}}{\textbf{##2}}% Name
   & $[$\glsentryuseri{##1}$]$% Units
   & ##3% Description
   & ##5% Page list
    \\% end of row
  }%
 % Sub entries treated the same as level 0 entries:
 %\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
  %\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##5}{##6}}%
 %% Nothing between groups:
 %\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
```

This gives me an output as shown in the image below:
[image: screenshot of output]

I edit the screenshot with some grey lines for the text which i would like to align (Using the `R` column specifier for fixed-width raggedright columns used in the pagelist). Mainly I would like to have the whole glossary `\textwidth`. I thought by making every column dependant on the `\textwidth` variable and adding the values up to 1 I would get a table which ultimately is as wide as the headerline. I've also tried using tabularx as the table environment, which failed (even though using the macro commands, e.g., `\tabularx \endtabularx`
). I've compiled an MWE (http://pastebin.com/McqsTPga, maybe not so minimal anymore) where you can see the problem for yourself.

I'm sorry for the somewhat lengthy post, but this is really bugging me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I would like to use this for my own work, could you tell me, how I get the page numbers to show? Do they need to be specified manually in the glossary file or do I need a special package for it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I thought by making every column dependant on the `\textwidth` variable
and adding the values up to 1 I would get a table which ultimately is
as wide as the headerline." This is almost true, but you forgot the intercolumn space that is automatically added. You can suppress that with `@{}` in the column specification. When I specify your tables with

```
\newglossarystyle{tabx3col}{%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}p{0.6\textwidth}@{}>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}}}%
  ...
```

and

```
\newglossarystyle{tabx4col}{%
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.12\textwidth}@{}p{0.08\textwidth}@{}p{0.6\textwidth}@{}>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}}}%
  ...
```

the alignment comes out as desired. It may be a better idea to not suppress the intercolumn space before and after the description. Then you have to make the description column (or any other column) narrower by 24pt.

Comment: With the `calc` package you can do `p{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` which takes care of the two "half paddings" relative to the column.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Seriously how do you know this stuff ;-D. I copied and replaced my third line of code with yours, but i cant compile it. I get an error that says `Exta alignment tab has been changed to \cr`. Any idea? If i modify the code manually with the `@{}` but leave the redefined column specifiers it works, but the first row in the first column shows an `@`.

Comment: Never mind, it was the `raggedleft` construct. I deleted it, and replaced it by the previously devined `R` column type. Works like a charm now. Thought i should share this beauty ;-) [Screenshot on Imgur](http://imgur.com/uOgTsaL).

Comment: --> By the way I have some questions regarding the glossaries package and since we're already on it: 1) How are the ##1 and so on keys set and where can i fond out about which value they represent and why do they have two hash tags `#` 2) In the second custom glossary style the name won't print out bold - in the first one it does. Why? 3) The optional argument of the `renewcommand` tells it how many placeholders it should expect. For the `\glossaryentryfield` the value is 5. I only count 4, which does not work while compiling.

Comment: @Sensei 1) The arguments are label, formatted name, description, symbol, number list. This is described in the glossaries manual, chapter 16. There are two hashes as they are parameters of `\glossaryentryfield`, not `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @Sensei 3) The `[5]` is the number of arguments of `\glossaryentryfield`, and they are the five I just listed.

Comment: @mafp Thank you for taking your time and answer my questions and excuse my laziness of not reading the manual very accurately.`\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\textbf{##2}}% Name
    & ##3% Description
    & ##5% Page list
    \\% end of row
  }` What does count as an argument here? The two backslashes also or only the #-ed ones? Do you mean chapter 1.6 on page 40?

Comment: @Sensei 2) Look closely at the definition of `\glsentryfield`: It uses `\textbf` when showing the acronym. However, `\textbf` does not have any effect on math, as in `\textbf{$\Delta E_{GP,i}$}`.

Comment: @mafp StackExchange is telling me not to discuss anymore ;-D. But really from the bottom of my heart, thank you I learned alot from you over the past few days. You have my gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

With `\usepackage{calc}` you can specify your `longtable` alignment as

```
\begin{longtable}{
  @{} % suppress the space at the left
  L{0.1\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
  L{0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
  p{0.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
  R{0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep}
  @{} % suppress the space at the right
}
```

You may want to remove the intercolumn spaces in the widest column; in this case

```
\begin{longtable}{
  @{} % suppress the space at the left
  L{0.1\textwidth}
  L{0.1\textwidth}
  p{0.6\textwidth-6\tabcolsep}
  R{0.2\textwidth}
  @{} % suppress the space at the right
}
```

Each column is preceded and followed by a `\tabcolsep` wide space; you have four columns, so, after suppressing the left- and rightmost spaces, six of them remain.

Comment: Or you use `\dimexpr ... \relax`

Comment: Thank you too for your answers, i already marked mafp's answer as the correct one. Never the less I tried them out and they worked great. Egreg's solutions seems like the cleanest to me. Thanks again.