# How to order an index (a symbol table) based on first occurrence in text?

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I'd like to add a symbol table to my math book. Since there is no meaningful/helpful way to order the index entries lexicographically, I'd like to order them chronologically, i.e. an index entry x will precede an index entry y if the first occurrence of x in the book precedes y's first occurrence. Is it possible to automate this kind of indexing using the MakeIndex program/makeidx package, or some other program/package?

P.S. To be more precise, I don't mean the absolute first occurrence of a symbol in the book; only those occurrences that I explicitly indicate should be considered.

Comment: Package `glossaries` is able to achieve this, as far as I can remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty much the default behaviour of the `glossaries` package. alpha_a and alpha_b got the same sort key so they are then sorted by first use. beta comes after them regardless of where it is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{alpha_a} {
name={\ensuremath{\alpha_a}},
sort={alpha},
description={your discription},
}

\newglossaryentry{alpha_b} {
name={\ensuremath{\alpha_b}},
sort={alpha},
description={your discription},
}

\newglossaryentry{beta} {
name={\ensuremath{\beta}},
sort={beta},
description={your discription},
}

\begin{document}
    \gls{beta} \gls{alpha_b} \gls{alpha_a}
    \printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

[image]

You would then probably want to look into a style that includes the units of the symbols if you are using it for math. Here would be a good starting point to look into this: [Custom glossary style: Make glossary as wide as \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106987/custom-glossary-style-make-glossary-as-wide-as-textwidth)

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'the units of the symbols'?

Comment: Since you are using it for math I just figured that you might want to define a glossary style that looks something like this: "E ... in kg/(m*s^2) ... Young's modulus ... Page 1" so it also contains the unit and not only the symbol.