# How can I get the first use of a glossary to show the full description?

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package with the `acronym` option to display multiple lists of acronyms and symbols. Using `\glsresetall` makes the next use of any acronym appear with the full description but this does not happen for the symbols. I can not use the acronym format for the other glossaries as they include values and units.

How can I make the first use of a glossary give the full format, as the first use of an acronym does?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomain, acronym, section=section]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{symbolvalue}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrysymbolvalue}{\GLsentrysymbolvalue}{\glssymbolvalue}{\Glssymbolvalue}{\GLSsymbolvalue}
\glssetnoexpandfield{symbolvalue}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package

\newglossaryentry{lightspeed}{
  name=\ensuremath{c},
  description={speed of light},
  symbolvalue={299792432},
  unit={\si{\meter/\second}},
  type=symbolslist
}

\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fps}{FPS}{Frame per Second}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
% put the glossary in the itemize environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{.4\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}p{0.3\textwidth}r}}{\end{longtable}}%
% have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   Sign &  Description & Value & Unit \\
  \endhead}
% have nothing between glossary groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \glssymbolvalue{##1}
  & \glsunit{##1}%
  \tabularnewline
}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=mylist]   % list of symbols
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms

\glsresetall

Now the first use of the acronym gives \gls{fps}

But the first use of the symbol gives \gls{lightspeed}, whereas I want it to give \glsdesc{lightspeed} (\glsname{lightspeed})

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Probably with `\glsfirst{<key>}`, which should come with a corresponding `first={speed of light~($c$)}` field in your glossary entry. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106557/117534

Comment: @Troy, Using `\glsfirst{<key>}`, gives the same result as `\gls{<key>}`, that is just *c*.

Comment: Have you added the `first=...` field to your `lightspeed` glossary entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic behaviour of `\gls` is to show the value of the `first` key on first use and the value of the `text` key on subsequent use. If the `text` key isn't set explicitly, it's assumed to be the same as the `name` key. If the `first` key isn't set, it's assumed to be the same as the `text` key.

So, with

```
\newglossaryentry{lightspeed}{
  name=\ensuremath{c},
  description={speed of light},
  symbolvalue={299792432},
  unit={\si{\meter/\second}},
  type=symbolslist
}
```

there's an implied `text={\ensuremath{c}}` and `first={\ensuremath{c}}`, which is why only the symbol is shown on first use.

The original `\newacronym` used by the base `glossaries` package without using `\setacronymstyle` automatically sets the `first` key to the long form followed by the short for in parentheses and the `text` key is set to the short form, so

```
\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fps}{FPS}{Frame per Second}
```

is basically doing

```
\newglossaryentry{fps}{
  name={fps},
  description={Frame per Second},
  first={Frame per Second (FPS)},
  firstplural={Frames per Second (FPSs)},
  text={FPS},
  plural={FPSs}
}
```

which is why on first use the description is shown.

(This is quite a simplistic way of dealing with abbreviations and doesn't allow much flexibility in style, so `\newacronymstyle` alters the way that `\gls` behaves so that entries defined using `\newacronym` are treated differently to entries that are defined directly with `\newglossaryentry`.)

One possible solution is to define a command for symbols that sets up the `first` key in much the same way that the original `\newacronym` works. This helps to maintain a consistent style for all your symbols.

For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nomain, acronym, section=section]{glossaries}              % use glossaries-package

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{15cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist} % create add. symbolslist


\glsaddkey{symbolvalue}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrysymbolvalue}{\GLsentrysymbolvalue}{\glssymbolvalue}{\Glssymbolvalue}{\GLSsymbolvalue}
\glssetnoexpandfield{symbolvalue}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\makeglossaries                                   % activate glossaries-package

% \newsymbol[options]{label}{symbol}{unit}{symbolvalue}{description}
\newcommand*{\newsymbol}[6][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#3},% symbol
   first={#6 (#3)},% description (symbol)
   symbolvalue={#5},
   unit={#4},
   type={symbolslist},
   description={#6},#1}%
}

\newsymbol{lightspeed}{\ensuremath{c}}{\si{\meter/\second}}{299792432}
{speed of light}

\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fps}{FPS}{Frame per Second}

\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
% put the glossary in the itemize environment:
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{.4\textwidth}>{\raggedleft}p{0.3\textwidth}r}}{\end{longtable}}%
% have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   Sign &  Description & Value & Unit \\
  \endhead}
% have nothing between glossary groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
% set how each entry should appear:
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
  & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
  & \glssymbolvalue{##1}
  & \glsunit{##1}%
  \tabularnewline
}
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=mylist]   % list of symbols
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype] % prints just the list of acronyms

\glsresetall

Now the first use of the acronym gives \gls{fps}

First use of \gls{lightspeed}.

Next use of \gls{lightspeed}.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

You might also want to consider overriding the default `sort` value as `makeindex` doesn't recognise LaTeX markup and so will see `\ensuremath{c}` as the sequence of characters `\` `e` `n` `s` `u` `r` `e` `m` `a` `t` `h` `{` `c` `}`.

There are several methods depending on what the other symbols are likely to be. If they're mostly just Latin characters in maths mode, then you could so something like:

```
\newcommand*{\newsymbol}[6][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={$#3$},% symbol
   sort={#3},
   first={#6 ($#3$)},% description (symbol)
   text={\ensuremath{#3}},
   symbolvalue={#5},
   unit={#4},
   type={symbolslist},
   description={#6},#1}%
}

\newsymbol{lightspeed}{c}{\si{\meter/\second}}{299792432} {speed of light}
```

In this case, the sort value is now just `c`.

Alternatively, you could sort by the symbol value if they're all constants:

```
\newcommand*{\newsymbol}[6][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={$#3$},% symbol
   sort={#5},
   first={#6 ($#3$)},% description (symbol)
   text={\ensuremath{#3}},
   symbolvalue={#5},
   unit={#4},
   type={symbolslist},
   description={#6},#1}%
}

\newsymbol{lightspeed}{c}{\si{\meter/\second}}{299792432} {speed of light}
```

In this case, the `sort` value is 299792432 which `makeindex` recognises as a number rather than a string.