# Glossary first use of symbol does not show description (long form)

Tags: symbols, glossaries, glossaries-extra, glossary

I'm attempting to generate two distinct glossaries—one for symbols and another for acronyms. However, I'm encountering an issue where the description for symbols doesn't appear on the first use in the text when using '\glsxtrnewsymbol{}'.
e.g. $\gls{x}$ only shows *x* and not *position x*

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple of hours now, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code is based on the excellent answer from Nicola Talbots in this post:
[Ordered symbols list with units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447208/ordered-symbols-list-with-units)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbols,acronyms,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}
% new keys must be defined before use
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}
\glsnoexpandfields
%
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
%
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position},unit={\si{m}}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity},unit={\si{\metre\per\second}}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\newacronym{ulm}{ULM}{ultrasound localisation microscopy}
\newacronym{sr}{SR}{super-resolution}
%
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
 \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
   \begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
   {\end{longtable}}%
 %
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
   \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit\\\hline
   \endhead}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
    & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
    & \glsentryunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
 }%
}
%
\makenoidxglossaries
%
% Hyperref setup
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black!50!black},
    citecolor={black!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
%
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=symbunitlong, title=List of Symbols, toctitle=List of Symbols]
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym, title=List of Acronyms, toctitle=List of Acronyms]
\tableofcontents
%
\chapter{Glossary Test}
First: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, \gls{ulm}, \gls{sr}\newline
Second: $\gls{x}$, $\gls{v}$, \gls{ulm}, \gls{sr}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: The `glossarystyle` is not relevant here, the symbols are not acronyms and so don't default to a special first style. This can be manually set through the `first` key which can be given in the optional argument to `\glsxtrnewsymbol`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386814/106162).

Comment: @Dai Bowen. Thank you for the quick answer. It was my understanding, that the 'first' key would default to the 'description'. But if I understand you correctly, I will have to set the 'first key' manually for each new symbol entry created using '\glsxtrnewsymbol'?

The problem only exists when using the '{glossaries-extra}' package with  '\glsxtrnewsymbol'. The '{glossaries}' package in combination with '\newsymbol' works as expected.

Comment: I don't understand, `\newsymbol` is not defined in `glossaries` or `glossaries-extra`. `\glsxtrnewsymbol` is just a wrapper around `\newglossaryentry`, `\newglossaryentry` defaults the `first` key to be the `text` key which defaults to the `name` key, only the `name` key is specified by `\glsxtrnewsymbol`, acronyms are handled exceptionally in this sense. You can define your own wrapper around `\newglossaryentry` which parses the symbol and description and passes that to the `first` key of `\newglossaryentry`, as the linked answer does with defining a `\newsymbol`.