# list of symbols with nomencl

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols, nomenclature

[How to create both list of abbreviations and list of nomenclature using nomencl package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl) 
i found this old question but it doent really help me.

I have the problem that i have a nomencl package already in my work and used it very often and now i want to do a list of symbols as well. I need 3 columns: Symbol, unit and discription.

Hope someone can help me.
Lea

here my code in a very short way:

```
\documentclass[ headsepline, plainheadsepline, frontsize=12bp, toc= listof, listof= chapterentry, DIV = calc]{scrreprt}


% Deutsche Sprache
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{url}

% Graphiken einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx}


% Tabellen schoen machen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Mathematik
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Schriften
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Schriftauszeichnung
\newcommand{\BegriffNeu}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Wichtig}[1]{\textit{#1}}

% --- Abkürzungsverzeichnis: ----------------------------
% START % Näheres siehe http://my.opera.com/timomeinen/blog/show.dml/68644
\usepackage{nomencl}
% Befehl umbenennen in abk
\let\abk\nomenclature
% Deutsche Überschrift
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
% Punkte zw. Abkürzung und Erklärung
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
% Zeilenabstände verkleinern
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
%--------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\minitabelle}[2]{
\begin{tabular}{c}
\hline 
#1 \\ 
\hline 
#2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead [\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\headmark}
\lofoot{Bachelorarbeit "In humanen Fluiden nachweisbare Krankheiten", Lea Schröder}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\printnomenclature

%here is my work done ;) but now i just put in some words ;)
etc.\abk{etc.}{et cetera}

usw.\abk{usw.}{und so weiter}

ASB\abk{ASB}{Arbeiter Samariter Bund}

DRK\abk{DRK}{Deutsches Rotes Kreuz}

q.e.d.\abk{q.e.d.}{quot erat demunstrandum}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: maybe 2m when u answer the unanswered????

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98241/usepackageglossaries-with-3-columns i even found an other example where they use glosserie with 3 columns, but glosserie is confusing for me. 
I have used my abk{}{} lots in my work and dont want to loose it. Please help me :=)

Comment: i try to use ur glosseryversion, but it doesnt work. How can i use my abk{}{} in glossery? Please help me ...