# \usepackage{glossaries} with 3 columns and groupheading

Tags: glossaries

I would like a glossary with 3 columns and groups heading: 
Here is the mwe, which I took (mainly) from: [\usepackage{glossaries} with 3 columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98241/usepackageglossaries-with-3-columns)

This works very well for me. I would just like to add the group names (as shown in the mwe) and some space below the group name. I tried but things looked ugly.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{A}{%
name={$\alpha$},%
description={alpha},%
user1={K},%
type=symbolslist,sort=ga
}

\newglossaryentry{B}{%
name={AAPL},%
description={apples},%
user1={box},%
type=symbolslist,sort=aa
}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
 {\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}}}%
 {\end{longtabu}}%% Set the table’s header: title row
%\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
% \bfseries Term & \bfseries Description & 
% \bfseries Units & \bfseries Page List
% \\\endhead}%
% No table header:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
% No heading between groups:
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\}%
% Main (level 0) entries displayed in a row optionally numbered:
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{##2}% Name
    & ##3% Description
    & \glsentryuseri{##1}% Units
    & ##5% Page list
    \\% end of row
 }%
% Similarly for sub-entries (no sub-entry numbers):
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
    % ignoring first argument (sub-level)
    \glstarget{##2}{##3}% Name
    & ##4% Description
    & \glsentryuseri{##2}% Units
    & ##6% Page list
    \\% end of row
 }%
% Nothing between groups:
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
}
\begin{document}
\null
\glsaddall


%\printglossary
\printglossary[type={symbolslist},style={mystyle}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you finally solve it? In case you did, you can post an answer yourself.

Comment: I posted the answer below, note that I slightly modified this mwe as \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader} appeared twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by just substituting:

```
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\\}%
```

with

```
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}\bigskip}\\}%
```

This adds a space also between the List of Symbols and the first entry (which does not have a title). If you do not want this you can always create a new glossary with another style without the bigskip.

Hope it helps,